# Find domain and range for $f(x)=x^2+4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Let $X\to Y$ so that $f(x)=x^2+4$

$X=\{6,9,2,8,5\}$ and $Y=\{27,85,40,8,12,29,63,68,17\}$

a) state the domain of $f$

b) state the range of $f$

I have calculated that the domain of $f(x)$ is all real numbers and that the range of $f(x)$ is $f\ge4$.

Therefore I thought that the correct answers were:

a) $\{6,9,8,5\}$

b) $\{27,85,40,8,12,29,63,68,17\}$

But this was wrong. Could anyone help me? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: 1) if you "calculated"  the domain was all real numbers, then why didn't you "think" the domain was all real numbers?  Why do you "calculate" and "think" two different and incompatible answers?

Comment: Why did you think 2 was not in the domain?

Answer (score 2):

Formally a function is a mapping between two sets, here $X$ and $Y$. The domain of $f$ is simply $X=\{2,5,6,8,9\}$. The range is the set of numbers in $Y$ that elements of $X$ map to: $\{8,29,40,68,85\}$. ($Y$ itself is the *codomain* of $f$.)

Comment: If $40$ was not in $Y$, would the domain of $f$ by $X$, or $X/\{6\}$? (I guess there would be a problem in the definition of $f$)

Comment: @anderstood If that, then to keep $f$ a well-defined function, the domain would have to be $X-\{6\}$.

Answer (score 2):

Definitions:

> Set of what can go into a function is called the Domain
>
> Set of what may possibly come out of a function is called the Codomain
>
> Set of what actually comes out of a function is called the Range.

Answer:

No. Domain is not $R$. The function is from X to Y. So essentially the domain is X. For range, plug all the values in X (there aren't many) one by one in the function and make a set of those values you get. I suppose it will be $\{40,85,8,68,29\}$. Set Y is codomain here..